# I have errors between two table, i can't show data

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3, relationship

i have 2 table Authors and Posts and i have relationship one to many:
this is Author model

```
public function author(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Post');
}
```

and this is Post model

```
public function author(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Author','author_id');
}
```

i I want to show all posts related to this author, i use this in Controller

```
public function author(Author $author, Post $post,$name)
{
    $authors = Author::where('name', $name)
        ->firstOrFail();
    $posts = $post->where("author_id", "=", $author->id)->get();
    return view('author', compact('authors','posts'));
}
```

and this in blade

```
@foreach($posts as $post) {{ $post->title }} @endforeach
```

but this doesn't show anything, what i do ??

Answer (score 1):

instead of $post just use Post module class..like..
`$posts = Post::where("author_id", "=", $author->id)->get();`

try..

Answer (score 0):

If you have setup the relationship, you only need to run the query on the main table (authors). Second Post query not required. Eloquent will know its linked (relationship) with Posts.

So to display you could simply:

```
@foreach ($authors as $author) 
   {{ $author->posts->title }}
@endforeach
```

Hope that helps...

Comment: this is not working! ````ErrorException in 802a64dd0c6b2877a7d37b8dab7df504d4e5ed3b.php line 36:
Trying to get property of non-object```` i'm trying to show info about author and it's working good but when i get all posts, this doesn't work !!